# avoiding calculation every time a class method is called

Tags: java, oop

I don't know if the title is appropriate but this is a design question.
I am designing a Java class which has a method which does heavy calculation and I am wondering  there is a clean way to avoid this calculation every time the method is called. I know that the calling code can handle this but should it always be the responsibility of the calling code?.

To elaborate - I was writing a class for thousand dimensional vectors with a method to calculate the magnitude.So every time this method will be called it will calculate the magnitude over all the dimensions.

Comment: Hide the calculation behind a cache, and only recalculate if the vectors are updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is called [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Answer (score 0):

Just cache the results in some structure internal to your class. Once the method is called, it looks if it has the previously calculated result in cache and returns it. In the other case it does the calculation and stores the result in cache. Be careful with the memory though.

Answer (score 0):

Use flag to indicate whether there is a change to your vectors or not. If there is a change, then the method should do a full calculation or apply the calculation to only the changes but you will need to becareful with all the implementations of the rest of your class and make sure that the flag is properly set every time the value is modified.

The second method is to use cache. This is done by storing the previously calculated result and look it up before doing the calculation. However, this method is only work well if you don't have many variety in the key values of your objects oterwise you will end up using a lot of memory. Especially, if your key value has type of double, it is possible that the key value will never be found if they aren't exactly equal.

Answer (score 0):

If the "thousand dimensional vectors" are passed in c'tor you can calculate the magnitude in c'tor and store in some private member variable.

Few things to take care of are:

- If there are methods to add / delete vectors or contents of vectors then you need to update the magnitude in those methods.
- If your class is supposed to be thread-safe then ensure appropriate write functions are atomic.

Answer (score 0):

How often are the magnitudes changed? Is this immutable? How much of the interface for the vector do you control? Specifically, do you have any way to identify rotations or other magnitude-preserving transformations in your 1000 dimensional space? You could just store state for the magnitude, flag when the value changes, and recalculate only when necessary. If your transformations have nice internals, you might be able to skip the calculation based on that knowledge.